# Spring - Cannot resolve MVC "view" thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I got a simple `HomeController.class`:

```
package com.example.tacos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Also I got a template called `home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hey</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyway I'm getting 404 in the browser and IDE's telling me Cannot resolve MVC "view" as you can see on the screen

**Folder Structure:**
[image: Folder Structure]

**Browser:**
[image: Browser]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi I had the same issue and I fixed it by delete the version of Thymeleaf so the pom file will be like :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

To solve this problem you should add path to `web app` package into Web Resource Directories.

1. Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S ("Project Structure" window opens)
2. Go to tab "Facets"
3. Then click tab "Web"
4. Add new package to "Web Resource Directories"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that in pom.xml I had this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Just started learning spring and don`t get dependencies well enough yet:)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the project as:

```
"Cannot resolve MVC view"
```

and the cause of it was `misspelling` with naming of the folder.

The structure was:

```
   |   |-- resources
   |   |   |-- template
   |   |   |   |-- customer.html
   |   |   |   |-- customerForm.html
   |   |   |   |-- customers.html
   |   |   |   |-- index.html
```

I needed to use the name as `templates` of the folder, but I had `template`.

Maybe, it'd be helpful for someone also.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my current project was created in another previous project.

Error was fixed after changing the project location.

Comment: This was the problem for me, thanks sir!

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who use Gradle, I had this in my build.gradle file;

```
implementation 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.1.2.RELEASE'
```

I have changed it to

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:3.0.4')
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the correct entry suggested by gumira in my pom.xml and I was still getting the error.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I had to fix [Maven Plugin not found in IntelliJ IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468269/maven-plugin-not-found-in-intellij-ide) instead and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I change the version of tomcat from 10.0.20 to 8.5.78 and sovle it.

Answer (score 0):

I previously added dependency

```
<!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

It doesn't work, even if I reload the Maven project.

Then I added  `<version>3.1.4</version>` to reload again, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, but I managed to resolve it.

I simply copied the following code snippet exists in pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and modified `artifactId` to `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`,then, I faced the same problem.

In my case, I removed the scope element and reloaded the configuration. It seems to be working fine for now.